# Can't select vertices through a reference image

Tags: vertices, image

[image]I'm trying to select 2 vertices at once, parallel to eachother in edit mode, to try and sculpt a banana for a school project. To make it perfectly symmetrical, I have clicked on the Y in the corner to be locked in a perfect angle. I am using a reference image right in the middle of the model, and when I hold down left click to select both vertices on both sides, it only selects the onre in front of the reference. The second I move the screen even slightly, it works(But that makes so it isn't symmetrical when I move it around).
Thanks beforehand!
//Typh0n

Comment: It's a bit difficult to know exactly what your problem is, but you could try hitting Shift-Z to go into wireframe mode or you could simply temporarily uncheck the eye icon against the Empty on the R/H Outliner panel to make the reference image invisible while you're selecting your vertices.

Comment: Alt Z allows you to switch to transparent (X ray) mode, you should be able to select the other vertex, but as John says, maybe give more details